# Pundit::NotDefinedError: unable to find policy when moving from Pundit 0.3 to 1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, pundit

When I am running rspec wit **pundit version 1.0** on one of my project spec classes I get multiple errors which I haven't seen before. However, when I'm switching to the previous version of pundit (0.3) everything works correctly.

Up to now what I have noticed is that with newer version of pundit @error in create function is not correctly assigned (instead of error class, I get an error message string from the error class).

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_execution_environment

  def authorize!
    authorize(@error || @errors)
  end
  private :authorize!

  def create
    @error = Error.new(error_params)
    authorize!
  end

  def error_params
    params[:error].permit(:message, :submission_id).merge(execution_environment_id: @execution_environment.id)
  end
  private :error_params
```

in spec/factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :error, class: Error do
    association :execution_environment, factory: :ruby
    message "exercise.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object (NameError)"
  end
end
```

in spec/controllers/error_controller.rb:

```
 describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'with a valid error' do
      let(:request) { proc { post :create, execution_environment_id: FactoryGirl.build(:error).execution_environment.id, error: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:error), format: :json } }

      context 'when a hint can be matched' do
        let(:hint) { FactoryGirl.build(:ruby_syntax_error).message }

        before(:each) do
          expect_any_instance_of(Whistleblower).to receive(:generate_hint).and_return(hint)
          request.call
        end

        expect_assigns(execution_environment: :execution_environment)

        it 'does not create the error' do
          allow_any_instance_of(Whistleblower).to receive(:generate_hint).and_return(hint)
          expect { request.call }.not_to change(Error, :count)
        end

        it 'returns the hint' do
          expect(response.body).to eq({hint: hint}.to_json)
        end

        expect_json
        expect_status(200)
      end

      context 'when no hint can be matched' do
        before(:each) do
          expect_any_instance_of(Whistleblower).to receive(:generate_hint).and_return(nil)
          request.call
        end

        expect_assigns(execution_environment: :execution_environment)

        it 'creates the error' do
          allow_any_instance_of(Whistleblower).to receive(:generate_hint)
          expect { request.call }.to change(Error, :count).by(1)
        end

        expect_json
        expect_status(201)
      end
    end
```

I get the error message

> Pundit::NotDefinedError:
>           unable to find policy `Pundit::ErrorPolicy` for `#<Pundit::Error: {"message"=>"exercise.rb:4:in`': undefined
>   local variable or method `foo' for main:Object (NameError)",
>   "execution_environment_id"=>1}>`

since error class is not correctly created. After that every test in error class fail.

My policies:

```
class AdminOrAuthorPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  [:create?, :index?, :new?].each do |action|
    define_method(action) { @user.internal_user? }
  end

  [:destroy?, :edit?, :show?, :update?].each do |action|
    define_method(action) { admin? || author? }
  end
end


class ErrorPolicy < AdminOrAuthorPolicy
  def author?
    @user == @record.execution_environment.author
  end
end
```

I have no such an problem with any other class.

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with the same problem for the last half hour, albeit using minitest, and the solution was to run `spring stop` and then rerun my tests. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, `spring stop` doesn't change anything in my case.